# VBA Interval Data

Tags: vba, date, excel

[image]

I need to summarize some info depending on the date. I mean, I need to sum some info if the date correspondig to that info is within an interval.

Is there anyway to do it?

I have seen "DATEDIFF", but what I need would be something like:

'If the data evaluted is whitin the next interval sum the value.

Hope you understood my question.

Thanks in advance.

EDITED: I added a pic to make it more understandable

Comment: do you want to enter the two dates in the sheet in certain values? Do you know how to make the changes? :)

Comment: yes, I know how to make the changes, thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it. I don't know where you want to use total, so now you just get a messagebox.

```
Sub SumBetweenTwoDates()

Dim total As Integer
total = 0

Dim firstDate As Date, secondDate As Date
firstDate = DateValue("20/11/2012")
secondDate = DateValue("20/12/2012")

For i = 1 To 5
    If Range("A" & i).Value >= firstDate And Range("A" & i).Value <= secondDate Then
        total = Range("B" & i).Value + total
    End If
Next i

MsgBox total

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks, I did not know I could use the sentence "IF" with dates.

Comment: You can use nearly anything with IF :P

Answer (score 1):

Use one formula in the cell you want the sum in:

Assuming the value is in A1:A100 and the dates are in B1:B100

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B1:B100>=DATEVALUE("1/1/2004"))*(B1:B100<=DATEVALUE("31/1/2004")),A1:A100)
```

will return the sum of the values fro January 2004